# ASP + SQL Server + NOW() = Headache

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I'm currently using Visual Web Developer 2010 (Express) and I'm trying to use the `NOW()` command within a SQL query to allow date selection but it doesn't work at random times and I'm lost to why it does this.

I'll give some examples, I'm from the UK my machine is set to standard time (sync with time.windows.com) and everything is fine but when I use the `= NOW()` it works but when it doesn't it seems the input date is mixed up, example below:

Currently my table is set as follows:

Table `crew_example`:

```
Column 1 : Date (In standard SQL time, so YYYY-MM-DD)
Column 2 : Initial
Column 3 : Surname
etc
```

My SQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT Date,
       Initial,
       Surname,
FROM   crew_example
WHERE  ( Date = { fn NOW() } )
ORDER  BY Date
```

This function normal work and is currently working with another SQL query that users `BETWEEN (DATE = { fn NOW() } + 1) AND { fn NOW() } + 6)` (Which I had trouble when I set this up before but it magically fixed itself and never thought anything about it).

The date output when I hardcode doesn't work if I use today's date `27/11/2014` but works when I "americanise" it to `11/27/2014` even though the output comes in UK format 27/11/2014 00:00:00

Is there a way to unify the dates? I'm new to SQL queries so not use if I can use the `NOW()` command but change it to `NOW()` in format `MM/DD/YYYY` instead of what looks to be `NOW()` using my UK date type.

EDIT: Seems `CURRENT_DATE` may work....but any ideas if this is the best way?

Regards
Jamie

Comment: Which sql dialect? T-Sql, MySql-Sql? nvm didn't see the tag.

Comment: Current_date() seems works for 30 seconds but now has died when I tried to add another filter...

Comment: I feel I should know this, but I cant really answer that as I wouldn't know.. The SQL Server is a Microsoft SQL Server via Visual Web Developer the date course via the explorer says :

" Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient) "

Comment: You tagged it with mysql so you are using an mysql server and not an mssql server, right?

Comment: Sorry @StefanOssendorf that was a misclick, I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In T-SQL I would use something like this:

```
Where Date between cast(getdate() as date) and cast(dateadd(d,1,getdate()) as date)
```

I've never used a "pure" date column, so I'm not sure if you need to get rid of the time with the cast.
For dateadd() see: [DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)
For cast() see: [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Pardon my rookieness here, but how do I build that into an already built query? For instance the query above, when I use your code I get the following error : 'Poorly formed cast function.'

Comment: Sry, the last cast was wrong i forgot "as date" ^^'

Comment: You sir, are a god among men. Thank you, will this work with anything as long as you change the 'as DATE' bit to the date column? So if my date column was Date_Current It would be :

`Where date_current between cast(getdate() as date_current) and cast(dateadd(d,1,getdate()) as date_current)`

or

`Where Date_current between cast(getdate() as date) and cast(dateadd(d,1,getdate()) as date)`

Comment: The last. Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx after the "as" is the datatype.  You are welcome :)